Overfitting in siamese neural network connected with signature verification
Im working on a signature verification problem where i should create a model which gives a averagelly good validation_accuracy in order to get a useful model for testing (goal is above 80%). I can see that my model is Overfitting since the training accuracy is almost 100% and my training loss is pretty low compared to the validation ones (66% highest peek). What can be the problem?
#Preprocessing step
def cropping(ref_img):
    # Find the outer contours of the white regions
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(ref_img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    if contours:
        # Find the bounding rect for all detected contours
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(np.concatenate(contours))
        return ref_img[y:y + h, x:x + w]
    return ref_img

steps = {}
augment = (random.random() < random_percentage)

loaded_img = cv2.imread(image, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
steps['Loaded'] = loaded_img

blurred_img = cv2.GaussianBlur(loaded_img, (3, 3), 0)
steps['Blurred'] = blurred_img

_, thresholded_img = cv2.threshold(blurred_img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
steps['Thresholded'] = thresholded_img

# Remove White Space
cropped_image_np = cropping(thresholded_img)
steps['Cropped'] = cropped_image_np

# Resizing (before skeletonization)
resized_image = cv2.resize(cropped_image_np, (IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
steps['Resized'] = resized_image

#resized_image = cv2.GaussianBlur(resized_image, (3, 3), 0)

#_, resized_image = cv2.threshold(resized_image, 0, 255,  cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# Skeletonization (after augmentation, if any)
#skeletonized_image = skeletonize(thresholded_img2 // 255)  # Skeletonize expects binary image
#skeletonized_image = (skeletonized_image * 255).astype(np.uint8)  # Convert back to 0-255 scale
#steps['Skeletonized'] = skeletonized_image

# Normalization
normalized_image = resized_image / 255.0
steps['Normalized'] = normalized_image

if augment:
    normalized_image = cv2.GaussianBlur(normalized_image, (7, 7), 0)
    steps['Noised'] = normalized_image

tensor_image = tf.convert_to_tensor(normalized_image, dtype=tf.float32)
tensor_image = tf.expand_dims(tensor_image, axis=-1)

#Used metrics
def euclidean_distance(vects):
    """
        Compute Euclidean Distance between two vectors
    """
    x, y = vects
    return K.sqrt(K.sum(K.square(x - y), axis=1, keepdims=True))


def contrastive_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    """
        Contrastive loss function
    """
    margin = 1.0
    return K.mean(y_true * K.square(y_pred) + (1 - y_true) * K.square(K.maximum(margin - y_pred, 0)))


def compute_accuracy(y_true, y_pred, threshold=0.5):
    """
        Compute accuracy based on a distance threshold
    """
    return K.mean(K.equal(y_true, K.cast(y_pred < threshold, y_true.dtype)))

UPDATE
Based on the answers i changed a few part of my implementation and now i was able to get a 75% of validation accuracy but right now im stucked at this point. Im using CEDAR dataset where i have 55 authors each has 24 genuine and 24 forged signature. Maybe im doing something wrong in the pair creation but i dont see any issue.
Pair creation:
def create_pairs(authors_list, path):
"""
Create pairs of genuine and forgery images for a list of authors.
Args:
    authors_list (list): List of author names.
    path (str): Base directory path where the images are stored.
Returns:
    tuple: A tuple containing two elements:
        - pairs (list): List of tuples, where each tuple contains two image paths.
        - labels (list): List of labels corresponding to the pairs, where 1 indicates a genuine pair and 0 indicates a forgery pair.
"""
genuine_pairs, genuine_labels = [], []
forgery_pairs, forgery_labels = [], []
for author in authors_list:
    genuine_list = genuine_images[author]
    forgery_list = forgery_images[author]

    # Generate positive pairs (genuine-genuine)
    for i in range(len(genuine_list)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(genuine_list)):
            genuine_pairs.append(
                (os.path.join(path, author, genuine_list[i]), os.path.join(path, author, genuine_list[j])))
            genuine_labels.append(0)

    # Generate negative pairs (genuine-forgery)
    for i in range(len(genuine_list)):
        for j in range(len(forgery_list)):
            forgery_pairs.append(
                (os.path.join(path, author, genuine_list[i]), os.path.join(path, author, forgery_list[j])))
            forgery_labels.append(1)

    del genuine_list, forgery_list

if len(genuine_pairs) < len(forgery_pairs):
    forgery_pairs = forgery_pairs[:len(genuine_pairs)]
    forgery_labels = forgery_labels[:len(genuine_labels)]
elif len(genuine_pairs) > len(forgery_pairs):
    genuine_pairs = genuine_pairs[:len(forgery_pairs)]
    genuine_labels = genuine_labels[:len(forgery_labels)]
else:
    pass

pairs = genuine_pairs + forgery_pairs
labels = genuine_labels + forgery_labels

return shuffle(pairs, labels)

Changed model:
    model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, (7, 7), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=alpha_value))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (5, 5), kernel_regularizer=l2(l2_value)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=alpha_value))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), kernel_regularizer=l2(l2_value)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=alpha_value))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), kernel_regularizer=l2(l2_value)))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=alpha_value))

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), kernel_regularizer=l2(l2_value)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=alpha_value))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())

model.add(Dense(256, kernel_regularizer=l2(l2_value), activation="relu"))  # Feature vector
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(256, kernel_regularizer=l2(l2_value), activation="relu"))  # Feature vector

The problem im facing is in the pictures:


if you have any question feel free to ask and i will send you every needed details!

Welcome to DS.SE !!!
TL;DR:
I suspect the main issue is that the model itself is too complex relative to the size of the dataset.
Main Observations and possible Issues
Symptoms of Overfitting

Metrics Discrepancy: Training accuracy approaches 100%, while validation accuracy plateaus below 66%.
High Validation Loss: Persistent high validation loss relative to training loss suggests poor generalisation.
Excessive Model Complexity: Five convolutional layers with numerous filters increase the risk of overfitting on a small dataset.


Definitions
Siamese Network Model
A Siamese network compares two input samples to measure their similarity. Given input images $x_1$ and $x_2$, the network maps them to embeddings $h_1$ and $h_2$ via a shared encoder $f_\theta$:
$$
h_1 = f_\theta(x_1), \quad h_2 = f_\theta(x_2)
$$
The Euclidean distance $d(h_1, h_2)$ is used to evaluate similarity:
$$
d(h_1, h_2) = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(h_{1,i} - h_{2,i})^2}
$$
Contrastive Loss
The contrastive loss is defined as:
$$
L(y, d) = y \cdot d^2 + (1 - y) \cdot \max(0, m - d)^2
$$
where $y$ is the true label ($1$ for similar, $0$ for dissimilar), $d$ is Euclidean distance, and $m$ is the margin.

Constructive feedback
1. Preprocessing pipeline
Strengths

Normalisation: Scaling pixel values to $[0, 1]$ helps to stabilise gradients during optimisation.
Cropping: Removing whitespace focuses on relevant features.

Areas for Improvement

Thresholding and Skeletonisation: Thresholding may erase fine details crucial for signature verification. Visualise results at each preprocessing step to verify feature preservation.
Augmentation Diversity: Current augmentation (Gaussian blur) is limited. Consider transformations like rotation, scaling, elastic distortions, and brightness adjustments.


2. Model Architecture
Strengths

Appropriate Design: Siamese networks suit verification tasks by focusing on embedding similarity.
Regularisation: Dropout is applied to dense layers.

Areas for Improvement

Excessive Complexity:

Five convolutional layers with many filters are unnecessary for small datasets. Simplify by reducing depth or filters.


Regularisation:

Add $l2$ regularisation to convolutional layers:
Conv2D(64, (3, 3), kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01))


Increase dropout rates (eg., from 0.3 to 0.5).


Global Average Pooling: Replace the Flatten layer with a global average pooling layer to reduce parameters and overfitting risk:
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())




3. Training Process
Strengths

Contrastive Loss: Designed for similarity tasks, encouraging close embeddings for similar inputs.
Accuracy Metric: Euclidean distance thresholding aligns with verification objectives.

Areas for Improvement

Learning Rate: The fixed learning rate ($1 \times 10^{-5}$) is likely too low. Use a higher initial value ($1 \times 10^{-4}$) with a scheduler, ehttps://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466/are-unbalanced-datasets-problematic-and-how-does-oversampling-purport-to-heg., ReduceLROnPlateau.
Early Stopping: Monitor validation loss to terminate training early and prevent overfitting:
EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5)


Validation Pipeline: Ensure no augmentation is applied to validation data.


4. Dataset and Evaluation
Areas for Improvement

Class Imbalance: Visualise the distribution of positive vs. negative pairs. Consider oversampling underrepresented classes or use class-weighted loss if imbalance exists. However, please note that there is considerable disagreement of the extent to which class imbalance can cause problems in machine learning models. See the following threads over at Cross Validated for further details:
What is the root cause of the class imbalance problem?
When is unbalanced data really a problem in Machine Learning?
Are unbalanced datasets problematic, and (how) does oversampling (purport to) help?

Dataset Size: If overfitting persists, consider:

Increasing dataset size via synthetic data generation.
Leveraging pre-trained models (eg., ResNet, EfficientNet) for feature extraction.


Cross-Validation: Use $k$-fold cross-validation to robustly assess generalisation.



Suggestions to Address Overfitting
Short-Term Adjustments

Simplify Architecture:

Reduce convolutional layers or filters.
Replace Flatten with GlobalAveragePooling2D.


Enhance Regularisation:

Apply $l2$ regularisation to convolutional layers.
Increase dropout rates.


Optimisation:

Increase learning rate and implement a scheduler.
Use early stopping.



Longer-Term Improvements

Augment Dataset:

Generate synthetic examples via transformations or GANs.


Alternative Architectures:

Fine-tune pre-trained backbones like ResNet or EfficientNet.




Summary
The primary cause of overfitting is the excessive complexity of the model relative to the dataset size. Short-term fixes include simplifying the architecture, increasing regularisation, and using a more dynamic optimisation strategy. For further improvements, consider expanding the dataset and leveraging transfer learning. Carefully monitor validation trends after implementing changes, and use cross-validation to help model generalisability.

Thank you very much for the detailed and well organized answer. I already see some point which helps a lot. I will try out the recommendations tommorrow and give you a feedback. :)

Thank you for your comments i achieved a 75% of success so im grateful. Unfortunately im still facing some issue. Right now the val_accuracy is like jumping from epoch to epoch and it seems noisy. And my model make a really good work on the positive pairs but with the negative ones they are not so far still. Maybe if you have any thought why is it?
